# Creating thumbnails for UICollectionview not maintaining aspect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm creating thumbnails for the cells in a collectionview and some of the images are not maintaining their aspect ratio. They're appearing stretched, i.e. image looks shorter and fatter. The weird thing is it's not happening for images taken with the camera from within my app. It's only happening for any images imported, such as from the photo library (even though they were taken with the camera) and for a couple of images I imported from the web. The content mode of the cell's imageview is set to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`. I'm also using `SDWebImage` for caching.

Can anyone tell me how to make sure the aspect ratio remains intact for all the images? Here's the code I'm using...

```
 - (UIImage *)imageByScalingToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, 0.0);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    UIImage *resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resizedImage;
}
```

Code inside of cellForItemAtIndexPath...

```
if ([self.allCacheKeys count] > 0) {
    // check to see if the cacheKeys arrays contains any keys (URLs)
    NSString *cacheKey = self.allCacheKeys[indexPath.row];
    if (cacheKey) {
        [self.imageCache queryDiskCacheForKey:cacheKey done:^(UIImage *image, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
            if (image) {
                // image is found in the cache
                NSLog(@"Image found in cache!");
                UIImage *thumbnail = [image imageByScalingToSize:CGSizeMake(ITEM_SIZE, ITEM_SIZE)];
                cell.imageView.image = thumbnail;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code that keeps aspect ratio of the images that you download from the web.

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithImage: (UIImage*) sourceImage scaledToWidth: (float) i_width
{
    float oldWidth = sourceImage.size.width;
    float scaleFactor = i_width / oldWidth;

    float newHeight = sourceImage.size.height * scaleFactor;
    float newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
    [sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

or following code does also same thing:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: The first method you posted worked, but only if I set the cell's imageview's content mode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill and set clipsToBounds to YES. But I then noticed I got the same result with my original code when using the AspectFill mode. Thanks for the help.